Is it "ok" to use different compression ratios in different bands, on a multiband compressor?
I read in a book or online that multi-band compressors should be used with the same compression ratio for each band.  I think the source said that the output might sound off otherwise (implying this introduces undesirable distortion?)
I see that some of the compressor presets in izotope neutron use different compressor ratios for different bands in the same compressor.
Who is right here, the author of the book, or izotope?

Like any effects processor, if you like the resulting sound, then of course it's OK!
If you were meant to keep the ratio the same on all bands, there would only be one ratio adjustment.
How you use a multiband compressor will depend greatly on the genre/idiom, and situation (track, submix, bus).
Especially in electronic music, where the effects can be instruments unto themselves, let your ears be the guide and don't worry about a scientific measure of distortion.  It's only objectionable if you object.
Of course, if you're looking to apply multiband compression on the main bus while mastering a recording of acoustic instruments, the approach and aims are completely different and the differences between the ratio/time/threshold, etc. on each band will be more subtle.  Much of the work of a multiband compressor would be better accomplished in mixing anyway:

Multiband compression is probably the most powerful and potentially
deadly audio process that’s ever been invented….Multiband compression
has been overused, and hyped in my opinion. It can easily produce very
unmusical sound or take a mix where it doesn’t want to be. This tool
requires careful judgment on the part of the mastering engineer.
Bob Katz – Mastering Audio: the art and the science

